# Integration of some peculiar functions like factorial function

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, gamma-function

Is factorial function integrable?

1. If yes please show me the proof

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Answer (score 3):

The factorial function is only defined on the set $\mathbb{N}$, hence no. 
There is a generalisation on $\mathbb{R}$ which is called the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

Comment: @taisan haque The primitive of a function is defined if it's at least piecewise continuous. So no you can't integrate $n!$ on natural numbers.

Comment: What do you mean with 'bound the function in natural number'?

If you want to know if you can extract the factorial function from the gamma function, the answer is yes: $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$.